# Scrapy python issue

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape data using scrapy framework of python but I am facing some issues. The problem is that after doing login .. it does not open the desired url and some issues related to session are occurring but I am not sure about it. The below code successfully login but after that it does not open the url. Kindly review the code and guide me. It is not opening the url in link variable of the below code.

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
import scrapy
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from first.items import FirstItem
from scrapy.http import FormRequest, Request
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib2
import csv
import time
import re
import locale
import os
import sys
import sys
import unicodedata
import base64


class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "craig"
    allowed_domains = ["linkedin.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.linkedin.com"]

    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={'username': 'name', 'password':password},
            callback=self.after_login
        )

    def after_login(self, response):
        # check login succeed before going on
        if "authentication failed" in response.body:
            self.logger.error("Login failed")
            return
        else:


            link="https://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/someurl"
            myRequest = FormRequest(link, callback=self.parse1, dont_filter=True)
            yield myRequest


    def parse1(self,response):

        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        path = "//*"
        html = str(hxs.select(path).extract())
        f=open("f.txt","w")
        f.write(html)
```

Comment: Post the errors you are receiving.

Comment: Could you post the crawl log. It could be that your `link` is being redirected to something else. By default scrapy goes through all redirections automatically, so your `parse1()` can receive response from a completely different link.

Comment: Why are you not using the API?